# Is there any better tool than "Send preview" to see emails?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, dataextensions, dynamic, triggered-send

I need to share the emails with others but should be done in a more smooth way than the horrible Send Preview functionality....

Is there any other tool different from sending the itself email to preview/construct the dynamic emails?

- UIX is terrible because is very limited to pagination by 25 to 25
- You can't search for a user (I know exists filtering DEs)
- You can't see the request payload that generate the email

Also I'm interested in a way to be anonymous and be able to see some emails to share with team.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: To see selected users you would be better off filtering them into a data extension then using it as a proofing de

Comment: Hi Mario did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inbox tools (you need to engage with your account executive for this- will cost you) provides a more complete diagnostic tool that which includes features like spam detective , code analysis and inbox placement. You can also use external tools like litmus. It is important to note that there is a lot of overlap between the two. In fact they are powered by the same rendering tool.

Comment: Litmus is great!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your current workflow entails, but it may be in your best interest to start creating dynamic emails with data extensions. We house all our email content across 15 brands within a Google spreadsheet. We update the sheet, update the data extension, and all the emails are rendered just like that.

Oddly, sometimes the link/URL to the email changes when you update the data extension, but sometimes it doesn't. You can speed up your process by rendering your emails via links, then just updating the data extension across all emails when you make change - that will allow your emails to keep the same link, and your previews to only have to be done once.

Comment: Do you use Classic or Builder?